# About A Problem I've Had About The Star Wars App

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch

First of all, good morning. 
I'm doing a project on React. The link of the data I'm trying to pull is https://swapi.co/api/films/1/.

My goal here is to list the movie data on my `MovieDetail` page. So far there is no problem title, release date, director, such as string character data can print the screen.

However, when I want to print the characters belonging to the movie, I cannot list the characters on the screen even though I have displayed the sequence in `this.state.characters` just before the return.
And although I have tried it with my own means for about 2-3 days with different methods, I have not succeeded. in the code now I'm just trying to get the characters from the movie.

I do not have any problems with data such as other title, date of publication. The current version of my project is available at https://github.com/kasim444/Javascript-Camp-2019/tree/master/challenges/star-wars-app. The real problem is the component in MovieDetails.js that I have experienced. I'd appreciate it if you could help me out. I don't know which point I'm missing.

I tried to do it with hook. I just tried doing it with the fetch method.

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import axios from "axios";

class MovieDetails extends Component {
  state = {
    director:null,
    episode_id:null,
    opening_crawl:null,
    producer:null,
    release_date:null,
    title:null,
    loading:true,
    characters:[],
  };
  async componentDidMount() {

    const movieId = this.props.match.params.id;
    let characterNames = [];

    const movieDetail = await  axios.get(`https://swapi.co/api/films/${movieId}/`);

    const charactersFetchLinks = movieDetail.data.characters.slice(0, 10);

    const promisesData = await charactersFetchLinks.map( link => axios.get(link) );
    axios.all(promisesData).then(value => value.map(val => {
      characterNames.push(val.data.name);
      // console.log(val.data.name);
    }));

    this.setState({characters: characterNames, loading:false});
    debugger;
  }



  renderLoading() {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  render() {
    // console.log(this.state.characters);
      return (
        <div>
          Test
          {!this.state.loading &&  this.state.characters.map(characterName => characterName) }
        </div>
      );
    }
  }

  export default MovieDetails;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `axis.all` is an async operation, you get to set `this.setState({characters: characterNames, loading: false})` before the data fetch is done.

So you can move the `this.setState` statement inside `then`.
*You can follow along*
[image: Edit so.answer.57130574]

*Note that I changed `value.map(val => {` to `value.forEach(val => {` to use `.forEach` instead of `.map` as it doesn't return any value (or do anything with it).*

```
class MovieDetails extends Component {
  state = {
   // omitted for brevity
  };
  async componentDidMount() {
    const movieId = this.props.match.params.id;
    let characterNames = [];
    const movieDetail = await axios.get(
      `https://swapi.co/api/films/${movieId}/`
    );
    const charactersFetchLinks = movieDetail.data.characters.slice(0, 10);
    const promisesData = await charactersFetchLinks.map(link =>
      axios.get(link)
    );
    axios.all(promisesData).then(value =>

      // I changed the `.map` to `.forEach` as you aren't returning anything.
      value.forEach(val => {
        characterNames.push(val.data.name);
        // console.log(val.data.name);
        this.setState({ characters: characterNames, loading: false });
      })
    );
    debugger;
  }

  renderLoading() {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <ul>
        {!this.state.loading &&
          this.state.characters.map(characterName => (
            <li key={characterName}>{characterName}</li>
          ))}
      </ul>
    );
  }
}
```

You can see the working screen below.
[image: demo]

Comment: thank you very much my friend ‍♂️. I missed that I had to do setState in Then . so is using forEach more performance than using Map ?

Comment: You're welcome @KasimŞEN. The reason for `forEach` was to rid of console warnings, which complained that there was no "return" statement :)